# raring repositories for odroid U3 ROS build

Tags: ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The UbuntuARM page includes a build for the Odroid-U3 using LUbuntu 13.05 (raring):
http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM

Unfortunately, the repository source removed the raring files, as it is out of support as of July 2014.   I have been unable to find an alternate site with raring repositories.  Also unfortunate is that there are only active ROS builds for raring armhf, as stated on that same page.

I could go back to the 12.04 Precise build, but I used to use that and there are a lot of problems and issues that were solved in raring.  So my main question is whether anybody knows if there will be a ROS armhf build for trusty sometime soon?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187016/raring-repositories-for-odroid-u3-ros-build/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been worried about this change from Ubuntu as well. It looks like they've end-of-life'd 13.04 and 13.10, and moved them to separate servers: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/07/17/ubuntu-13-10-saucy-salamander-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2014/

It looks like the raring armhf repository is available on http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ ; you'll have to update your sources.list to match.

I've been thinking about doing Indigo builds for Trusty, but haven't had time to get a new build farm going.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2014-07-18**:
Thanks Austin!  I just did a build from scratch and those repositories work fine.